# automatically add entries to hosts file

Tags: windows, dns, routing, hosts

I have a hosts file on my dropbox in which I create shortcuts to all kinds of ip's that I use often (server dev is added as d, stackoverflow is added as so and so on).
Over time I have built quite a list. This list is purely personal. On each reinstall of my machine, with each VM I use I have to copy my hosts file from Dropbox into the machine I want to use. The other way around, when making a change in one of the hosts files, I have to take care that stuff keeps up to date somehow.
I would prefer to simply have one place (machine-independant) where I can store my entries and then simply ímport/use them on my targetmachine. I have thought about using the company DNS but again, these shortcuts are strictly personal.

Suggestions as to how I could do this? I was thinking about some import/regfile or so......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a batch file to copy your hosts file from your Dropbox directory to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` this will simplify the things for you.

Comment: this is the batch-file that does the trick:          '@echo off
xcopy %~dp0hosts c:\windows\system32\etc\hosts /EQ /H /R /Y /U'