# Load multiple hosts files

Tags: macos, bash, hosts

Think I already know the answer. But looking for a unicorn.

Anyone know if there is a way to link one hosts file to another, or load 2  or more different hosts files?

I have a hosts file that has entries personal to me. My company also has a pretty extensive hosts file that has entries needed for work.

As of now, every-time one of our pesky admins update an IP in need to manually recombobulate my personal entries with work entries using yucky copy and paste.

My hope is to tell my local hosts file, or my workstation, to also reference a host file that resides in say, a shared repository. I'm pretty sure this is not easily done, but wondering if anyone has an idea for a solution that is more elegant than just copy and paste (or writing a script that basically dose just that)?

I've already viewed [automatically add entries to hosts file](https://superuser.com/questions/725370/automatically-add-entries-to-hosts-file) and [/etc/hosts can't be a symbolic link?](https://superuser.com/questions/1311955/etc-hosts-cant-be-a-symbolic-link), not quite the same problems, but close.

Again, maybe a tall order. Hoping for a nifty trick, but don't have my hopes up...

Suppose I should mention, running MacOS/bash 5...

Answer (score 0):

Your best option may be to have a copies of the Hosts file in a storage folder and then have a script run to merge the two or more files.  Then have the script overwrite the Hosts file and this will allow you to organize your entries in different files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).